# Patch value not working with nested inputs Reactive forms Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm working with Angular 5 and reactive forms, mi form is been created dynamically with a JSON that is been provided by the backend, there are some special inputs that are nested 3 levels and it works great with radio buttons but when the inputs are group of nested checkbox the  patch value do not change the value of the checkboxes, this an example of mi structure

```
this.cvForm = this._fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required]],
  lastname: ['', [Validators.required]],
  nested: this._fb.group({
    level1: this._fb.group({
       level2: this._fb.group({
          level3: this._fb.group({
             checkbox: [false, Validators.required]
         })
       })
     }),
   }),
 });
}

 this.cvForm 
    .get([
      'nested',
      this.nested,
      'level1',
      this.level1,
      'level2',
      this.level2,
      'level3',
      this.level3,
      'components',
      checkbox
    ]).patchValue({ checked: setValue });
```

EDIT:

I've been doing a lot of test with examples that you guys provide and I appreciate all your help. But I saw that the patch value it's not saving o changing the value at first click, when I click the checkbox once the view changes but the value in the form is still false and the second click on the checkbox set value to true in the form, but the view is changed so, basically the patch value and set value are setting the value till the second click in the form. And I have no idea why is that happening.

Comment: how are you using patch value ?

Comment: What's the data with which you're trying to set the value?

Comment: I edit the code, @SachinGupta and I add the patch line, that is how are we using the patch value.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I'm trying to set the value with a boolean.

Comment: @GeekDev, I've updated my answer. Please check to see if that works for you.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I tried your solution and also the others that people posted and any of them works but I see something, the patch is working but, is setting the value 2 times so when I click the first time it goes true and then false again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours of research and testing I found that reactive forms in angular does not support the `object.property` syntax to set the value for depth level values, instead I did this:

```
this.cvForm.controls['nested'].controls['level1'].controls['level2'].controls['level3'].controls['checkbox'].value['checked'] = newValue;
```

That fix my problem, thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only concerned about setting the value of the checkbox, please consider using [**`patchValue`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchValue).

And instead of getting the exact `FormControl` either by calling the `get` method on the `FormGroup` or by doing what you've done can be error-prone in case of nested `FormGroup`s.

A simpler way would be to create an Object value that matches the structure of the form and then set the value that you want to set.

Here, give this a try:

```
setValue: boolean = true;
...
this.cvForm.patchValue({
  nested: {
    level1: {
      level2: {
        chekbox: setValue
      }
    }
  }
});
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-patch-value-deeply-nested-component?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to pass the string array which will give you the `FormControl` that you are looking for.

```
this.cvForm 
.get([
  'nested',
  'level1',
  'level2',
  'level3',
  'checkbox'
]).patchValue(setValue)
```

this should work for you. You dont need to pass an object to patchValue as this is a single formControl. You would need to pass object if you are patching values for multiple form controls in a single `FormGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for how to update the checkbox value, try this way (useful for future similar searches)

My Form structure
[image]

changing the checkbox value

```
this.form.controls.completed['controls'].completed.value = MyBooleanValueHere;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqjny3 it worked for me

```
this.cvForm.patchValue({
  nested: {
    level1: {
      level2: {
        level3: {
          chekbox: true|false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You are patching multiple levels of `FormGroup` using that object. The OP only wants to patch value for a single control.

Comment: Yeah I see, the question got an update. But i do nearly the same with the following lines:
`get checkboxControl() {return this.cvForm.controls['nested'].controls['level1'].controls['level2'].controls['level3'].controls['checkbox'];}` but of course via get it's much smarter.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your stackblitz code. Only the answer given here